# Extremely slow Vite page loading - it was working yesterday

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I'm working on a project using Laravel 10, Vue, Inertia and Vite. During development I use `npm run dev` to serve Vite. For weeks it worked flawlessly, but suddenly it's extremely slow, like to take 4 minutes to load a page.

Slowness is only for the first time I open a page: Vite loads all the Vue components and it take it ages. But after that, subsequent requests for the same page/components are as fast as they should be.

Code hasn't changed - in fact I tried going back in git to last week commits, with the same result.

It's possible that environment had changed as last days I had to try a lot of things in the development machine (Linux Ubuntu) in order to work with an old, legacy project (installing php7.1, node 14, etc...) but even if I have tried to undo all the changes, it looks like something is still wrong.

In the same machine I have other Laravel projects not using Vue/Vite, and they are fast as usual, so I discard problems with Apache, php-fpm or network.

System is never more than 50% of load, both memory and cpu usage.

I've tried with node 14 and node 20, same result.

If I build the project for production (`npm run build`) it builds in less than 1 minute and then website works fast as it should.

Looking at the log running npm run dev, I can see that it takes ages to load some components:

```
 vite:hmr [self-accepts] resources/js/Pages/Admin/Import/Index.vue +8s
  vite:import-analysis 17.40ms [15 imports rewritten] resources/js/Pages/Admin/Import/Index.vue +31s
  vite:transform 120.29ms /resources/js/Pages/Admin/Import/Index.vue +31s
  vite:time 11903.08ms /resources/js/Pages/Admin/Import/Index.vue +31s
  vite:cache [memory] /node_modules/.vite/deps/@inertiajs_vue3.js?v=0e978822 +31s
```

```
  vite:load 11695.47ms [fs] /resources/js/Pages/Admin/Category/Index.vue +2m
  vite:hmr [self-accepts] resources/js/Pages/Admin/Category/Index.vue +6s
  vite:import-analysis 17.36ms [14 imports rewritten] resources/js/Pages/Admin/Category/Index.vue +2m
  vite:transform 66.00ms /resources/js/Pages/Admin/Category/Index.vue +2m
  vite:time 11768.75ms /resources/js/Pages/Admin/Category/Index.vue +2m
  vite:cache [memory] /node_modules/.vite/deps/@inertiajs_vue3.js?v=0e978822 +2m
```

The initial load takes anything between 7 and 10 seconds, that is acceptable.

As said, files (components) are exactly the same they were last week, nobody has touched a thing in the code, and even tried with an old commit with same result.

And as said, that is the behavior when I launch `npm run dev` and then open a page for the first time. Once the components for a page have been loaded first time (taking minutes), next time I open that page it loads instantly. If I stop Vite and start it again with npm run dev, again the same page will take minutes for the first load. It looks like after "caching" components, it runs fast, but the everytime Vite founds a component, it takes minutes to compile it.

I'm sure it has something to do with the machine, something I've changed during the experiments last week, but I cannot find what it could be.

Any idea where could I look at? I can use `npm run build`by now, but that's innaceptable for developing on the long term.

**** Update ****

If I disable HMR from vite.config.js it works fast as it should. So issue is when HMR is trying to load components. Not sure what that means, but maybe it's a clue.

**** vite.config.js ****

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: '192.168.64.3',
            https: true,
        },
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
            detectTls: 'my-project.linux-dev.com',
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        basicSsl(),
    ],
});
```

The machine at 192.168.64.3 is a multipass (Docker) machine. As said, it has more than enough resources (never go more than 50% load, and RAM is no more than 30% in use).

The server is exposing an URL over HTTPS with a self signed certificate.

This configuration was working last week without any issues.

If I set `hmr: false` keeping the rest of the configuration, it works as fast as expected - but not so convenient for developing, of course.

Comment: have you tried re installing packages? packages version change? You could try to delete node_modules then run npm i or npm ci to delete and install at the same time

Comment: Also try to clear cache in npm `npm cache clean --force` before installing

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth yes, I tried it. I tried with node 14, 16 and 20, and every time I changed node version I cleaned everything (node_modules, package-lock.json, cache clean) and reinstalled everything (npm install). Same behavior :(

Comment: I updated the post, as I've tried something else: if I disable HMR from vite.config.js it works fast as it should. So issue is when HMR is trying to load components. Not sure what that means, but maybe it's a clue.

Comment: might as well include the vite .config.js here so that people can see what type of settings you have(even if you used default settings). btw it is better to return that package-lock.json file

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth you're right, I forgot to include it. I've edited the post to include it.